# Jquery set the css class of a fontawesome icon in a nested child

Tags: jquery

I have the following html structure

```
<div class="menu">

   <h1> Test  <span><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span> </h1>
   <div class="menu_container_1"> my itemm</div>
</div>

<div class="menu">

   <h1> Tests  <span><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span> </h1>
   <div class="menu_container_2"> my itemm</div>
</div>
```

SO whenever i click on the menu class i would like to change the i class hence changing the actual font awesome icon but this fails to work.

In my jquery code i have

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
      jQuery(".menu").on('click', function(event){
          event.preventDefault();

          jQuery(this).children('h1>span>i').find(jQuery(".fa")).removeClass('fa-plus')
             .addClass('fa-times') //this fails

      })
  })
```

But the above doesnt work. I suspect the issue to be my targeting of the i child. How can i resolve this or where am i going wrong?

Comment: `.find(jQuery(".fa"))` should not use `jQuery`.  Just give find the selector string

Comment: Though the `.children('h1>span>i')` may also be an issue because the `i` tags are not children of the element, and children may have the same restrictions with the selector you give it as closest() does.  So this should probably be `find('h1 > span > i.fa')`

Comment: ^ Making note that `.fa` is not a child of the `i`.  It *is* the `i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".menu").on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    jQuery(this).find('i.fa')
      .removeClass('fa-plus')
      .addClass('fa-times')
  })
})
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">

  <h1> Test <span><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span> </h1>
  <div class="menu_container_1"> my itemm</div>
</div>

<div class="menu">

  <h1> Tests <span><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span> </h1>
  <div class="menu_container_2"> my itemm</div>
</div>
```